# JQuery-- how do i move (not revert) a draggable div to another div when i do an action?

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

how do i move (not revert) a draggable div to another div which is a droppable when i do an action? for example how do i move a draggable div from div-A to div-B if i click a button?

Answer (score 0):

To move an element to another when you click in a button (or another element that you delegate) you can do this:

```
//Delegate a function for the button
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#elementInsideDivA').appendTo($('#divB')); //Move element into another
});
```

I don't know if it solves your problem, but I hope it helps.